# azure ad login is not working in ios app while microsoft authenticator app is installed

Tags: ios, swift, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have built an ios app which is using azure ad login and it was working fine but after install microsoft authenticator app the azure ad login is not working anymore
in fact the alert which does say " app wants to use 'microsoftonline.com' to sign in"
not coming
and uninstalling the authenticator  my ios app can login via azure ad again

```
let kClientID = [clientid]
let kGraphEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
let kAuthority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxx"
let kRedirectUri = [URI]    
let kScopes: [String] = ["user.read"]
```

```
func initMSAL() throws {
        
           guard let authorityURL = URL(string: kAuthority) else {
            print("Unable to create authority URL")
            return
        }
        
        let authority = try MSALAADAuthority(url: authorityURL)
        
        let msalConfiguration = MSALPublicClientApplicationConfig(clientId: kClientID,
                                                                  redirectUri: kRedirectUri,
                                                                  authority: authority)
        
        self.applicationContext = try MSALPublicClientApplication(configuration: msalConfiguration)
        self.initWebViewParams()
    }
    


    func initWebViewParams() {
        self.webViewParamaters = MSALWebviewParameters(authPresentationViewController: self)
    }
    


    func acquireTokenInteractively() {
        guard let applicationContext = self.applicationContext else { return }
        guard let webViewParameters = self.webViewParamaters else { return }
        
        let parameters = MSALInteractiveTokenParameters(scopes: kScopes, webviewParameters: webViewParameters)
        parameters.promptType = .selectAccount
        
        applicationContext.acquireToken(with: parameters) { (result, error) in
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Could not acquire token: \(error)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let result = result else {
                print("Could not acquire token: No result returned")
                return
            }
            
            self.accessToken = result.accessToken

            let aduser=MicrososftUser.init(id: result.uniqueId ?? "", mail: result.account.username ?? "", givenName: result.account.username ?? "", surname: "");
            self.adLoginRequest(aduser: aduser)
            //self.getContentWithToken()
        }
    }
```

info.plist

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>msauth.$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.674973595907-gsm9poebb8u1vvb28rvt7osv</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>msalv2</string>
        <string>msaalv3</string>
        <string>msauthv2</string>
        <string>msauthv3</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Inter.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-Black.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-ExtraLight.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-Light.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-SemiBold.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-ExtraBold.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-Medium.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-Thin.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                    <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                    <string>Main</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>processing</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

when i click on azure ad login button the following error is showing in debug window

`Could not acquire token: Error Domain=MSALErrorDomain Code=-50000 "(null)" UserInfo={MSALErrorDescriptionKey=Failed to delete broker key with error: -34018, MSALInternalErrorCodeKey=-42708, MSALCorrelationIDKey=4A0C2756-0173-7068-AC4F-AFEC1C84BCB3}`

could any one help me with this issue

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Have you added msalv3 and msalv2 to the info.plist application query schemes?

Comment: @Paulw11 no i added msauthv2 and msauthv3

Comment: @Paulw11 i added also msalv2 and msalv3 but still the problem exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solving the issue by disabling the access from my app to authenticator.
Adding the following line in initMSAL function

`MSALGlobalConfig.brokerAvailability = .none`

got help from following links:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/issues/845

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/blob/dev/MSAL/src/public/configuration/MSALGlobalConfig.h#L74